# Scala casting to generic list invalid type

Tags: scala, generics, casting

Any of you have an idea as to why the following compiles:

```
def foo() =
    someObjectOfTypeFutureAny.asInstanceOf[Future[List[Bar]]]
foo()
```

Whilst the following does not:

```
def foo[T]() =
    someObjectOfTypeFutureAny.asInstanceOf[Future[List[T]]]
foo[Bar]()
```

It comes down with the error 'List[T] is invalid type for the resulting GraphQL type Seq[Bar].

someObjectOfTypeFutureAny is what I receive from an Akka actor ask (which returns a List[Bar])

I'm using [Sangria-Graphql](http://sangria-graphql.org/)

I built a basic application casting a list to another list using a generic, passing the function the generic like in the example above, which worked. So I'm not really sure where my error here is coming from.

My actual code:

```
def complexFieldResolver[Val, T](arguments: (Context[Unit, Val]) => List[String]): Field[Unit, Val] = {
    Field("solution",
        ListType(solutionEntityType),
        arguments = OptionalEntityIdArgument :: OptionalEntityIdsArgument :: Nil,
        resolve = ctx =>
            viewActor.ask(Query(NodeType.Solution, arguments(ctx))).asInstanceOf[Future[List[T]]]
    )
}
```

Gets called like this: `complexFieldResolver[ApplicationEntity, SolutionEntity]((context) => getArguments(context, "solutionentity", context.value.solution))`

The code being called:

```
case NodeType.Solution =>
    graph.Vertex.findSolutionEntitiesByIds(ids).asInstanceOf[List[SolutionEntity]]


def findSolutionEntitiesByIds(entityIds: List[String]): List[models.SolutionEntity] =
```

Comment: `asInstance` `Off` ?

Comment: @rumoku He wants to turn off the instance ;P

Comment: Show us definition of `Field` constructor. As soon as you look closer into it, you'll understand the answer.

Comment: @rumoku Thanks! I took a look at Field's apply method:

    `def apply[Ctx, Val, Res, Out](....)`

Without really understanding what's going on I rewrote my: `Field("solution"`, to: `Field[Unit, Val, Any, Any]("solution`.

Looking around in the code now to see why exactly this works, haven't found much yet as I'm pretty new to Scala.

Comment: Your small example *does* compile.